# On navigation, background color changes to black

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm encountering an issue where the background color of my app changes black when a button is clicked to navigate to another page. I've tried using theme to change the background color in MaterialApp but for some reason it doesn't work. This is my main.dart file

```
void main() {
  initializeDateFormatting('tr_TR', null).then((_) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/home": (context) => HomePage(),
        "/": (context) => LoginPage(),
        "/welcome": (context) => WelcomePage(),
        "/calendar": (context) => CalendarPage(),
        "/announcements": (context) => AnnouncementsPage(),
      },
      initialRoute: "/home",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

In home page, I'm trying to create a navigation to announcements page as below.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/duyurular');
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AnnouncementsPage(),
        ),
      );
    });
  },
  child: AppText(
    text: "More",
    context: context,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: responsive.screenWidth / 25.71,
    color: AppColors.darkMagenta,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
  ),
),
```

The result I get when I click on "More" text.
[Background is black and texts have yellow underlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhqkP.png)

Comment: share announcements page code

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your AnnouncementsPage code inside

```
Scaffold( body: …your page code
```

Comment: Hi, quick question: when I click on 'more,' the announcements page shows up with the scaffold added, but the bottom navigation bar doesn't. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

## Try wrapping pages with `Material` widget

```dart
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Material(
      child: ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work but someone suggested wrapping it with scaffold and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: I saw the other answer while I was editing. I was in the process of searching why it needs a Material ancestor. Eventually, I clicked on the add button by accident, then I just left it there. Lol!